# How to populate concurrenthashmap from multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I have a ConcurrentHashMap which I am populating from multiple threads.

```
private static Map<DataCode, Long> errorMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<DataCode, Long>();

public static void addError(DataCode error) {
    if (errorMap.keySet().contains(error)) {
        errorMap.put(error, errorMap.get(error) + 1);
    } else {
        errorMap.put(error, 1L);
    }
}
```

My above `addError` method is called from multiple threads which populates `errorMap`. I am not sure whether this is thread safe? Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Any explanation of why it can skip updates will help me to understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether this is safe depends on what you mean. It won't throw exceptions or corrupt the map, but it can skip updates. Consider:

1. Thread1: errorMap.get(error) returns 1
2. Thread2: errorMap.get(error) returns 1
3. Thread1: errorMap.put(error, 1+1);
4. Thread2: errorMap.put(error, 1+1);

A similar race exists around the `keySet().contains(error)` operation. To fix this you'll need to use atomic operations to update the map.

On Java 8, this is easy:

```
errorMap.compute(error, oldValue -> oldValue == null ? 1L : oldValue + 1L);
```

On older versions of Java you need to use a compare-and-update loop:

```
Long prevValue;
boolean done;
do {
  prevValue = errorMap.get(error);
  if (prevValue == null) {
    done = errorMap.putIfAbsent(error, 1L);
  } else {
    done = errorMap.replace(error, prevValue, newValue);
  }
} while (!done);
```

With this code, if two threads race one may end up retrying its update, but they'll get the right value in the end.

Alternately, you can also use Guava's [AtomicLongMap](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html) which does all the thread-safety magic for you and gets higher performance (by avoiding all those boxing operations, among other things):

```
errorAtomicLongMap.incrementAndGet(error);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It makes sense now. If possible, can you provide an example how I can use Guava `AtomicLongMap` for this?

Comment: @david, added example. Simple, no? :)

Comment: what? it is very simple.. Awesome. Also, now how does `errorAtomicLongMap` declaration will look like? I replaced map with AtomicLongMap, I got an error.

Comment: It's not completely a drop in replacement. You'll need to declare it as just an `AtomicLongMap<DataCode>`, and when reading out of it either use `get(error)` or the `.asMap()` method

Comment: I see, when I tried like this I still get an error: `The constructor AtomicLongMap<DataCode>() is undefined`. This is what I am trying: `private static AtomicLongMap<DataCode> errorHolder = new AtomicLongMap<DataCode>();` I have never used this before so having some doubt.

Comment: Use the create function: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html#create()